# Join, group by and where with linq

Tags: c#, linq, join, group-by

I have three tables :

> - Requests ( requestId, userId, languageId, text, timePosted)
> - RequestLanguages ( requestId, languageId)
> - UserLanguages (userId, languageId) - all languages user knows

In Requests languageId is language on which request is asked but in RequestLanguages languageId is language to which user wants translation. There can be few languages user wants translation to, not only one.

I need to make query in Linq in which I will select all requests on languages user knows that wants to be translated on languages user also know (that needs to be a list).

I used group by but I'm not really good at this. I don't know how to JOIN Requests and RequestLanguages on requestId and store all languageId user wants translation into list!

I tried something like this:

```
using (var context = new WordsEntities())
        {
            List<short> languagesIKnow = (from ul in context.UserLanguages
                                          where ul.userId == userId
                                          select ul.languageId).ToList();

            var requests = (from rl in context.RequestLanguages
                            group rl.languageId by rl.requestId into p
                            select new
                            {
                                languageTold = p.ToList(),
                                reqId = p.Key
                            }
                            );
            List<ShowRequests> list = new List<ShowRequests>();
            foreach (var r in requests)
            {
                ShowRequests Req = from req in context.Requests
                          where req.requestId == r.reqId
                          && languagesIKnow.Exists(y => y == req.languageId)
                          && languagesIKnow.Intersect(r.languageTold).Any()
                          select new ShowRequests
                          {
                              languageAsk = req.languageId,
                              languageTold = r.languageTold,
                              userId = req.userId,
                              text = req.text,
                              picture = req.pictureExtension,
                              audio = req.audioExtension,
                              timePosted = req.timePosted
                          };
                list.Add(Req);



            }
```

but i can't assign Req as class ShowRequests..

Comment: Some sample data (input and output) would be helpful in understanding your description.

Comment: This old question appears to be abandoned, and little feedback has been offered to the two answer posts below. I think this can be closed as "unclear" now.

Answer (score 1):

you can go like this for joining those 2 tables and then add your where clause after that.

```
var query = from request in Requests 
            join requestLanguage in RequestLanguages 
            on request.LanguageId equals requestLanguage.LanguageId
```

Answer (score 1):

I think these simple joins are all you need

```
var query = from request in db.Requests
            join requestLanguage in db.RequestLanguages
              on request.requestId equals requestLanguage.requestId
            join userLanguage in db.UserLanguages
              on requestLanguage.languageId equals userLanguage.languageId
            where request.requestId == requestId && userLanguage.userId == userId
            select request;
```

Comment: I need to store those languageIds from RequestLanguages in a list.